# Previewing the layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am new to android development. Also new in using android studio.
And when I started to create a new project, the content_main.xml and does look like this[image: content_main.xml]

But not to other xml
[image]

And here is the output

[image]

How can I even edit the layout, when I can't see it. Also when i drop anything from the palette, I cannot see it.

Comment: the other file is menu layout.

Comment: yes. but how can i edit the content_main.xml if i can't preview the layout.

Comment: you have not opened the content_main.xml in any of your posted images. you have to click on file to view its preview.

Comment: check Constraint layout dependency in gradle

Comment: It is the first picture. Where can i find it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the android version to some lower in xml.
Change from 28

Answer (score 0):

Do not use content main. It is for including inside activity_main.xml. Make everything inside your main layout and finnaly you can see the result.
And don't forget that ConstraintLayout needs constraints for all elements.
First of all read about other layouts and learn how to use them.

Comment: But also my main layout is just like the preview shown in content_main.xml

Comment: Because it contains <include> node with content_main.

Comment: where is this <include> tag?

Comment: You have it inside activity_main.xml.